# How to setup return session and request param values in a mocked HttpContextBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to test a method in an **.ashx**. (Yes, an ASP.NET webform site.)

```
private Mock<HttpContextBase> moqContext;
private Mock<HttpRequestBase> moqRequest;
private Mock<HttpSessionStateBase> moqSession;

[Test]
public void ShouldDownloadFile()
{
    moqContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    moqRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    moqSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();

    moqRequest.Setup(x => x.Params["PrintId"]).Returns("1981");
    moqSession.Setup(x => x["VoucherId"]).Returns("164282");

    moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);
    moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.Session).Returns(moqSession.Object);

    var handler = new VoucherPrintServices();

    handler.DownloadReport(moqContext.Object);
}
```

The test failed at

```
moqRequest.Setup(x => x.Params["PrintId"]).Returns("1981");
```

saying,

> Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.Params["PrintId"]

But then what is the correct way to mock an `HttpContext` with session and request parameter values?

Comment: As the message says, that accessor is not virtual so it cannot be overridden/mocked for the test. The Params property however is virtual, which means you can replace it with an actual NameValueCollection that contains that key

Comment: I would be a lot easier to help if you show how the context is used in the method under test. That way we know exactly what needs to be mocked. Because you might only need the one context mock and setup everything on that.

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, that accessor is not virtual so it cannot be overridden/mocked for the test.

The `NameValueCollection.Params` property however is `virtual`, which means you can replace it with an actual `NameValueCollection` that contains that key.

```
var parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("PrintId", "1981");
moqRequest.Setup(x => x.Params).Returns(parameters);
```